# Accessing collection in an agent in Anylogic

Tags: arraylist, collections, anylogic, agent

I am new to any logic. Can anyone give me pointers over my issue ? The problem I am facing is that I have created a collection in an agent. I am sending a msg with arraylist as its Type from one agent to another. In the connections, in action I am trying to add received arraylist item into another collection. When I print the collection in received agent's connections, it shows me my message but if i try to print same collection in statechart or try to access it in the same agent. It gives me an empty collection.
If any further detail is required then I can discuss that over messages. Please let me know if anyone could solve my problem.

I have tried to change all my Arraylist of collections from arraylist data type to my desired customized datatype. After sending I tried to add data in a new collection within the receiving agent but while printing it still gave me empty collection.

Comment: Hey, suggest you try to simplify this (rather complex) problem. Try it with 1 variable of a primitive type (`int`...), see if you get that to work. Then, understand what ArrayLists are and how they work... Replying to this question would be a whole lecture on Java and OOP. See some tips on writing good SOF questions for AnyLogic here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow